# How do I batch sign transactions using Freighter API?

Tags: wallets

I want to be able to sign multiple transaction with one approval(signing) or one click.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.